# option tag not shown in firefox

Tags: dojo

I have the following code in html:

```
<select>
    <option text="item9" value="9"></option>
    <option text="item10" value="10"></option>
</select>
```

The select shows up as blank in firefox. There are no elements. But it works in IE. The following works in both:

```
<select>
    <option text="item9" value="9">item9</option>
    <option text="item10" value="10">item10</option>
</select>
```

I am using the following dojo code to create the dropdown:

```
dojo.byId("sel1").add(dojo.create("option", { text:optionText,     value:docNode.childNodes[i].getAttribute("id") }));
```

How do I create

```
<option text="item9" value="9">item9</option>
```

with dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need is:

```
<select>
    <option value="9">item9</option>
    <option value="10">item10</option>
</select>
```

The `text` attribute is non-standard.

You can use:

```
dojo.byId("sel1").add(dojo.create("option",{ 
    innerHTML:optionText,
    value:docNode.childNodes[i].getAttribute("id")
}));
```